# how to get the size of the image which in UIImage picker controller before choosing it?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to get images from `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`, before choosing the image from image library, i want to know the memory size of that particular image . I'm using

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

{   

    UIImage * img = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];
    size_t imageSize = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(img.CGImage) * CGImageGetHeight(img.CGImage);
    printf("\n the image size is :%zd",imageSize);
    [self useImage:img];
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    UINavigationController* navController = self.navigationController;
    UIViewController* controller = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];


}
```

here the image size which I'm calculating is incorrect, what exactly the image size in image library  is different from image size I'm calculating.
And i want to know the image size before picking the image
 Can anyone help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Yo can get size of your picked image in JPEG format like this:

```
UIImage * img = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0);
yourImgSize = [imageData length];
```

Or in PNG format

```
UIImage * img = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img, 1.0);
yourImgSize = [imageData length];
```

**EDIT**

It will be in bytes, you may consider usefull to divide by 1024 untill you get to your desired unit

Comment: what is (img,100) it is showing as too few arguments warning.Actually I'm using 696kb image using above I'm getting image length as 232500bytes which is 227.05078125 kb.